# Swift refactoring: How quickly change all access modifiers to "public"

Tags: swift, xcode, refactoring

I'm extracting a large part of the app to a separate framework and would like to apply `public` access modifier to every variable, class and function. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: I am already suprised if I can rename a property in Xcode, without it trowing errors... I doubt if your asked functionality exists...

Comment: Dont do it quickly... do it carefully. ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it in Find navigator. Choose Replace -> Text -> Matching Word and write something like this:

[image]

Choose your framework by clicking on "In Workspace". Than click "Replace all".

Do this with classes and structures. But be attentive with `func` and `var/let` because it can be inside some function.

Comment: But methods marked `private func` will become `private public func` ... ...

Comment: @Moritz then he can do private to "" or private directly to public ,  he won't do it blindly he should know what currently exists

Comment: To be honest, I'd do this by hand. However, if you insist in doing it "quick": instead of searching for text, search with regex, and use: `^(\s*)(func|let|var)`, and the replacement: `$1public $2`. This however has some edge cases, so review every replacement carefully.